# Compute the matrix sim R with Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

Matrix A is a m by n+1 has reducedn QR factorization and `A = Q_hat * R_hat`. Moreover,

`A = Q_hat*diag(1/q(m,1) ,..., 1/q(m, n+1))*diag(q(m,1) ,..., q(m,n+1))` This is equal to `A = simQ * simR`.

How do I find simR in matlab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qr factorization in Matlab can be performed like `[Q,R] = qr(A)`.

Given your last equation A = simQ*simR. You can split this equation into:

> simQ * simR(:,1) = A(:,1)
>
> simQ * simR(:,2) = A(:,2)
>
> and so on.

These are now simple equations of the form `Ax = b`and can therefore be solved like `x=A\b;`